# Puppeteer on Raspberry pi zero w

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, raspberry-pi, puppeteer

I want to run a node js script with puppeteer on Raspberry pi zero w,
but I'm getting this error:

```
(node:5699) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: 1: /SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: �: not found
/SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: 1: /SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: ELF: not found
/SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: 2: /SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: p#: not found
/SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: 3: /SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: p#: not found
/SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: 4: /SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: @l�: not found
/SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: 5: /SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: pX: not found
/SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: 6: /SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: pX: not found
/SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: 7: /SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: 4: /SteamCheaper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: ��q: not found
```

Can you tell me, what can I do with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puppeteer uses the bundled Chromium by default. The error says it was not able to launch it.

You should manually install the Chromium and make Puppeteer use that version instead.
Assuming that you have installed it in `/usr/bin/chromium`, something like this will do the job:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    product: "chrome", executablePath: "/usr/bin/chromium",
})
```

Comment: Should be `executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'` but `product: 'chrome'` was the key

Answer (score 4):

Here is the basic code for getting Chrome headless and Puppeteer working on the Raspberry Pi, with a fresh install of Raspbian Stretch Lite.

```sh
sudo apt install chromium-browser chromium-codecs-ffmpeg
sudo apt install npm
npm install puppeteer-core@v1.11.0
```

in node.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'});
```

Comment: For context, `chromium` is the normal package and `chromium-browser` is the "customized Raspberry version" https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=339831